# Use of PROVIDE keyword in linker script of ARM processor

Tags: arm, stm32, nxp-microcontroller

what is the difference between statement at line-4 and 5???
And what are the problems comes when defining symbol with leading undersore??

code:

```
SECTIONS
{
  .text :
     *(.text)
     _etext = . ;        // line-4
     PROVIDE(etext= .);  // line-5

}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question as text. Just a link and even a link to an image is bad practice as the question cannot be properly indexed and the link is likely to break in the future.

Comment: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/PROVIDE.html

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer can easily found using google

Comment: Is this gnu's linker?  linker script is specific to the linker (tool) not necessarily the target (arm).